# *ngSwitchCase não está renderizando o elemento conforme condição

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho dois componentes que devem ser renderizados conforme uma expressão:

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let avaliacao of avaliacoes" [ngSwitch]="escolha_layout_avaliacao">
      <app-avaliacao-produto-modelo-emoji *ngSwitchCase="emoji" [avaliacao]="avaliacao"></app-avaliacao-produto-modelo-emoji>
      <app-avaliacao-produto *ngSwitchDefault [avaliacao]="avaliacao"></app-avaliacao-produto>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
escolha_layout_avaliacao: string

ngOnInit() {
  this.buscaDadosLayout()
}

buscaDadosLayout(){
  this.escolha_layout_avaliacao = "emoji"
}
```

Porém o `ngSwitch` está renderizando o `default`., ignorando a condição que tem como valor emoji.

Eu testei no html através da interpolação: `{{escolha_layout_avaliacao}}` e o valor printado é "emoji", mas mesmo assim ainda não é renderizado aquele componente, e sim o definido no `*ngSwitchDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema substitua:

```
*ngSwitchCase="emoji"
```

por

```
*ngSwitchCase="'emoji'"
```

Nesse caso, o angular estava tentando comparar a variável "escolha_layout_avaliacao" com a variável "emoji" que não existe.

Adicionando aspas simples ("'emoji'") você vai comparar a variável "escolha_layout_avaliacao" com a STRING "emoji".